# float value of python list is printing more zeros

Tags: python

I am new to python and when I am trying to print the value of list which hold the float value and strings are printing more zeroes in float values. why this behavior in python can anyone please explain.

```
list = ['abcd', 786 , 2.23, 'john', 7.23 ,'Deepak','Umesh']
#tinylist = [123, 'john']
print list # Prints complete list
```

o/p

```
['abcd', 786, 2.23, 'john', 7.2300000000000004, 'Deepak', 'Umesh']
```

why so many zeroes are coming after 7.23

Comment: which python version you are using??

Comment: Please don't user `list` as a variable in Python.

Comment: I am using 2.6.1 version but I also tried one more case in 2.7.13 where i am adding two float number. a=.269720378209382082
b=.368273469247000000
c=a+b and the o/p is 0.637993847456 which is not exactly same of above two values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, like any programming language, can't represent all floating-point values exactly; sometimes precision problems will cause issues like you see. For any calculation, 7.2300000000000004 is so close to 7.23 that it shouldn't matter.

Resources to learn more: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html
http://floating-point-gui.de/

Also, it's better not to use `list` as a variable name, because that shadows a built-in.

Comment: I'm sure sure this is a floating point issue, but the actual original code snippet does not produce that output, at least in Python 2.7 on my system

Comment: @Chris_Rands is it possible that the output depends on hardware/OS/etc.? Also, maybe OP is using a seriously old version of Python...

Comment: @AmitKumar if you're using a version of Python earlier than 2.7, update. In the meantime, learn about the ```format``` method to control how your output looks.

Comment: @perigon Thanks for your comment.